# why to use same table alias and do SELF JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one `sql script` in that `one table` is used with `two alias` and make a `JOIN` on it 
but I need to understand why and when it is needed to do so
please elaborate ?

```
SELECT

             ISNULL(MarketValue,0)   
        FROM
            (                  
            SELECT TOP 5

                Delta,
                MarketValue     
            FROM
                (
                SELECT DISTINCT

                   FormatNumber(SUM([CURRENT].MarkToMarket), 0, ',', 0) AS Delta,
                    AVG([CURRENT].Mark) * SUM([CURRENT].Position) AS NumericPosition,
                    FormatNumber(AVG([CURRENT].Mark) * SUM([CURRENT].Position)* CASE WHEN [CURRENT].SecurityType IN ('Equity','Equity Option') THEN 100 ELSE 1 END, 0, ',', NULL)  AS MarketValue
                FROM
                    NAV [CURRENT]
                    LEFT JOIN
                    NAV Compare ON
                    [CURRENT].PurchaseLotId = Compare.PurchaseLotId AND
                    Compare.Date = '2012-06-06'
                WHERE

                    [CURRENT].SecurityType not in ('Equity')
                GROUP BY

                ORDER BY
                    NumericDelta DESC
            ) Movers
        FOR XML PATH ('TR'), TYPE
        ) AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

Why it is used like  FROM
                    NAV [CURRENT]
                    LEFT JOIN
                    NAV Compare ON
                    [CURRENT].PurchaseLotId = Compare.PurchaseLotId AND
                    Compare.Date = '2012-06-06'
```

> NAV is only one table then what is the purpose to do take two alias of same table NAV [CURRENT] and NAV Compare and use LEFT JOIN?

please elaborate me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing 2 records from the table

You need two different alias's to represent the two different records.

So for example if you had a table called Employees: (Id, Name, ManagerId) where ManagerId is the Id of an Employee's immediate manager

```
ID    Name     ManagerId
1      CEO        null
2     YourBoss      1
3      You          2
```

and you wanted to run a query that selected you and the name of your boss:

```
SELECT emp.Name, mgr.Name
FROM Employees emp INNER JOIN Employees mgr on emp.ManagerId = mgr.Id
WHERE emp.Id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

NAV is being joined with itself, so there are actually two instances of every column in nav. Current and compare are used to differentiate between them.